# Are JAXB library not included by default in JBoss 4.2.2?

Tags: web-services, deployment, jaxb, jboss-4.2.x

i created a ws client using wsconsume tool of jboxx 4.2.2 (it's mandatory that i use jboss 4.2.2 for my project).

When i archived and deployed the jar, and used it in my project, it threw a class not found exception.

After the investigation, it turned out that required jaxb libraries are not included in jboss 4.2.2 by default.

I can simply copy the required libraries in from the client folder to server/default/lib from , but i was wondering if there is a configuration i can change to include the client folder by default?

sidenote: i find it strange that i can generate the client but not be able to deploy it without copying the jaxb libraries or adjusting the config, am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After the investigation, it turned out that required jaxb libraries are not included in jboss 4.2.2 by default.

Yes.  JBoss 4 is ancient, and pre-dates JAXB 2.

> i was wondering if there is a configuration i can change to include the client folder by default?

No, you'll need to include the required libraries either in your application itself, or in `server/default/lib`.

> i find it strange that i can generate the client but not be able to deploy it without copying the jaxb libraries or adjusting the config

Generating code is just an exercise in outputting text. It doesn't in itself require the libraries that it generates code to use.